Wix does not allow to add NS records
I want to delegate internal.infraheads.com to my internal nameservers, but I depend on Wix as they enforce the use of their NS servers. And they don't support adding NS records required for NS delegation. What can I do in this situation except move away from Wix?

Wix has a subscription business model - this means, that it is in their best interest to force you to do as much as possible with them and only with them, to be able to sell you the most expensive plan. So for them it makes sense to make delegation impossible or at least hard.

What do you mean by saying hard? Do you have any ideas?

You can always proxy the content their system creates to a self-hosted site. Be aware, that you must rewrite a lot of targets, as they use abslute URLs instead of realtive ones.

NS is a Name server. A NameServer means that if a DNS request is made, one of the name servers is queried for the correct DNS.
You do not want to change the NameServers, especially not if one points to service X and one points to service Y.
But you're lucky, because that is not at all what you need to do.
You want to manage internal.infraheads.com from another location.
You can do this by creating a new DNS record elsewhere, for example: wix.mydomain.ext
Now, in Wix add a CNAME internal.infraheads.com and point it to wix.mydomain.ext
Now, whenver you change the DNS of wix.mydomain.ext, internal.infraheads.com will match automatically, as each DNS request is automatically forwarded.
Alternatively, you can choose to host the domain elsewhere, and set the CNAME for Wix in your DNS on the different server. Wix does support external DNS even if it doesn't like it.

I need to delegate the control of the internal.infraheads.com to another DNS server. As I understand, you propose purchasing another domain and doing the trick described in your last four paraggraphs; why would I do that anyway? If getting a separate domain is an option, I can use that with another DNS provider that allows subdomain delegation and forget about infraheads.com that traps in into wix.

Did I say that I want to change the nameservers? I want to add two more for subdomain delegation.

If you want to add/change the nameservers, you will have to change all the nameservers, and move DNS editing away from Wix. You can still point the records back to wix, but you have to manage the entire DNS elsewhere then. That is your only option based on the comments you given. One last thought. If internal.domain.ext is really only to use for an intranet site, you can just set this up in your local DNS server to overrule the external domain. This will make it so that from outside of your LAN, internal.domain.ext does not resolve, but internally it does.

To whoever downvoted, please explain why. The answer is correct.
